# NIntegrate convergence problem

Tags: numerical-integration, code-review

I have an integral that does not converge satisfactorily for some values and appears random. I have included the code (and plot). However, since the integral depends of imported data, it cannot be tested. Nevertheless, any help through observation alone will be highly appreciated

```
II[t_, s_] := (288*(-5 + s^2 + 2*t + 
     t^2)^2)/(((1 - s + t)*(1 + s + t))^6)*(0.25*
  N[Pi]*((-5 + s^2 + 2*t + t^2)^2)*
  UnitStep[t - Sqrt[3] + 1] + (-(t - s + 1)*(t + s + 1) + 
   0.5*(-5 + s^2 + t*(2 + t))*
    Log[Abs[(-2 + 2*t + t^2)/(3 - s^2)]])^2);
Omega[k_] := (1./12)*
NIntegrate[((t*(2 + t)*(s^2 - 1))/((1 - s + t)*(1 + s + t)))^2*
   PSpecFunc2[0.5*(t - s + 1)*k]*PSpecFunc2[0.5*(t + s + 1)*k] // 
  Rationalize[#, 0] & // Evaluate, {s, -1, 1}, {t, 0, Infinity}, 
WorkingPrecision -> 40, PrecisionGoal -> 8, MaxRecursion -> 20, 
Method -> {"MonteCarlo", "SymbolicProcessing" -> 0}];
k = Table[i, {i, 10^Range[3, 16, 13./500]}];
GWdata = Table[
Omega[k]*0.68^2, {k, 
10^Range[3, 16, 13./500]}];
```

In this code the "PSpecFunc2" is an interpolating function created from data that, unfortunately, cannote be imported here. Regardless, when I ran the code, I obtain the following plot
[image]
It is mostly alright except for the regions where the data appears random. Mathematica throws NIntegrate::maxp error stating that the integral failed to converge after 50100 integrand evaluations. I know it is impossible to diagnose this without being able to run it, however any hints will be extremely helpful.

Comment: Your integrand contains singularities. For instance for `1-s+t==0`. I guess you need to treat them in the PrincipalValue sense by providing `Exclusions`. Something along these lines `NIntegrate[....,Method -> PrincipalValue,  Exclusions -> {1-s+t==0}]`. You are using MonteCarlo for speed, however, unless you regularize the integrand somehow (by adding small imaginary part to the denominator), it has no chances to converge. Rather, I would go with above option and reduce `PrecisionGoal` and `AccuracyGoal`.

Comment: Thanks. I will try to take care of the singularity issue. However, should I not use Monte Carlo in this case?

Comment: Integration in the principal value sense assumes a very specific way how the singularity is approached from both sides. Monte-Carlo is a stochastic method that "knows" nothing about these intricacies. However, if you regularize the function, MC can be very efficient.

Comment: I tried adding the principal value method. Mathematica states that it can only be used for 1d integrals.

Comment: I was awaiting this question. Write 2d integral as two 1d integrals. Have a look also here https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/NIntegrateIntegrationStrategies.html#122144792

Comment: Are you referring to the section on "Duffy's coordinates"?

Comment: I was suggesting to look at the Singularity Handling section in general.

Comment: If `PSpecFunc2` is an arrary (a list) , the expression `PSpecFunc2[0.5*(t - s + 1)*k]` with single brackets cannot be evaluated I think.

Comment: It's actually an interpolating function. I edited the question.